# How do you turn off System-DNS bound to localhost

Tags: systemd, systemd-resolved

```
root@deathstar:~# lsof -ni|grep -v firefo
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd    1 root   59u  IPv4 187418      0t0  TCP 127.0.2.1:domain (LISTEN)
systemd    1 root   60u  IPv4 187419      0t0  UDP 127.0.2.1:domain
```

How do I turn it off?

(it's not the systemd-resolved.service)

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely odd.

Normally, systemd-resolved would be holding these ports.

Post the output of...

```
lsb_release -a

netstat -pluten

systemctl status systemd-resolved

dpkg -l | grep -e bind -e dns -e resolv
```

Also describe your runtime environment - dedicated server (host level) or some sort of container (LXD/LXC/docker).

I'll spin up an LXD container with a similar config + see if I can recreate this.

Also, mention any packaging changes you've made related to DNS, especially related to the libnss-resolve package + any systemctl commands + any changes to systemd config files you might have made

Almost looks like somehow systemd-resolved died + connections propagated up to the initial, host level, systemd process, which makes no sense.